# How to install Java using terminal?

Tags: command-line, install, java

I want to install Java entirely from the terminal without using any GUI. Can anybody give some instructions? I know that I download it with `curl`, but it seems that `curl` doesn't play quite nicely with Oracle, and I have no idea what to do after downloading it.

Edit: I want to use Oracle's JDK

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To entirely use a (bash) shell to install e.g. Java 8u112 JRE do the following:

Download:

```
cd ~/Downloads
curl -v -j -k -L -H "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u112-b15/jre-8u112-macosx-x64.dmg > jre-8u112-macosx-x64.dmg
```

Mount:

```
hdiutil attach jre-8u112-macosx-x64.dmg
```

Install:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/Java\ 8\ Update\ 112/Java\ 8\ Update\ 112.app/Contents/Resources/JavaAppletPlugin.pkg -target /
```

Clean-up:

```
diskutil umount /Volumes/Java\ 8\ Update\ 112 
rm jre-8u112-macosx-x64.dmg
```

---

To install the latest Oracle JDK (at the time of writing this answer it's Java 8u121 JDK) the various paths (besides the version number) are slightly different compared to the older JRE version. The URL contains an additional directory (i.e. /e9e7ea248e2c4826b92b3f075a80e441) and the dmg file contains a .pkg file instead of an installer app:

```
cd ~/Downloads
curl -v -j -k -L -H "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u121-b13/e9e7ea248e2c4826b92b3f075a80e441/jdk-8u121-macosx-x64.dmg > jdk-8u121-macosx-x64.dmg
hdiutil attach jdk-8u121-macosx-x64.dmg
sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/JDK\ 8\ Update\ 121/JDK\ 8\ Update\ 121.pkg -target /
diskutil umount /Volumes/JDK\ 8\ Update\ 121
rm jdk-8u121-macosx-x64.dmg
```

Comment: I was trying to install from the command line but could not find a `pkg` installer online any more. I saw that `JavaAppletPlugin.pkg` in the DMG but thought it was not what I wanted because the name is misleading. I tried using `installer` the way you did but it hung just like the GUI version. I forced quit it and used the options I had used before with `pkg` installers and this worked:
 `installer -verboseR -dumplog -pkg "/Volumes/Java 8 Update 131/Java 8 Update 131.app/Contents/Resources/JavaAppletPlugin.pkg" -target / -store`
The `-store` emulates installation from the Mac App Store.

Comment: @hmj6jmh The question only related to the Java SDK! You are trying to install the runtime...

Answer (score 25):

The best/safest way to install Java on macOS is with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/); just type this:

```
brew install oracle-jdk --cask
```

Or if you don’t have Homebrew installed already, just type this command first:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew install oracle-jdk --cask
```